# SQL working strange

Tags: sql

When I execute this SQL code:

```
select id, opis, vidrabota, tipprov, hitnost, valuta, drzava, zbirnaprov, tip_zbirprov, kanal
from dev_1450autoebanktip
where opis is null or Opis like case when isnull('','') = '' then Opis else '%' + '' + '%' end
and VidRabota = case when isnull('','') = '' then VidRabota else '' end
and TipProv = case when isnull(0,0) = 0 then TipProv else 0 end
and Valuta = case when isnull('','') = '' then Valuta else '' end
and drzava is null or Drzava = case when isnull('','') = '' then Drzava else '' end
```

I get this set of results:
[image]

But when I add one more condition (last row):

```
select id, opis, vidrabota, tipprov, hitnost, valuta, drzava, zbirnaprov, tip_zbirprov, kanal
from dev_1450autoebanktip
where opis is null or Opis like case when isnull('','') = '' then Opis else '%' + '' + '%' end
and VidRabota = case when isnull('','') = '' then VidRabota else '' end
and TipProv = case when isnull(0,0) = 0 then TipProv else 0 end
and Valuta = case when isnull('','') = '' then Valuta else '' end
and drzava is null or Drzava = case when isnull('','') = '' then Drzava else '' end
and KANAL = case when isnull(0,0) = 0 then KANAL else 0 end
```

I am losing one row in the result. What is causing this change?

[image]

Comment: i dont get your where clauses, what are you trying to achive?

Comment: It's a code from Delphi, I get the values as the parameters from code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kanal is NULL in the last row.

```
and KANAL = case when isnull(0,0) = 0 then KANAL else 0 end
```

boils down to

```
and KANAL = KANAL
```

But this is not true for NULL, because NULL is the unknown value. When comparing null with null the result is neither true nor false, but unknown. Thus the added criteria dismisses the last record.

There is one thing I'd like to add: Use parentheses when mixing `AND` and `OR`. For instance

```
a = b or a = c and d = e
```

means

```
a = b or (a = c and d = e)
```

because `AND` has precedence over `OR` and you may want the expression to mean

```
(a = b or a = c) and d = e
```

Use parentheses in order to avoid any mistakes.

Comment: How can I avoid this and show the rows with null values in KANAL column also? If I add KANAL IS NULL OR part in the last condition, than I never get the chance to show only the rows with for example value 1 in column KANAL

Comment: Usually you'd build the query dynamically and only add the criteria when a kanal restriction is desired. But as you want to have a static query that works for any combination of desired criteria, you can use: `and ( isnull(@kanal,0) = 0 or kanal = @kanal)`. This checks: either no restriction is given or the restriction is met. You should re-write all your criteria accordingly.

Comment: My code in Delphi at the moment looks like this:
select id, opis, vidrabota, tipprov, hitnost, valuta, drzava, zbirnaprov, tip_zbirprov, kanal
from dev_1450autoebanktip
where Opis like case when :Opis = '' then Opis else '%' + :Opis + '%' end
and VidRabota = case when :VidRabota = '' then VidRabota else :VidRabota end...
But I am never getting records with NULL values in them, that is why I had to insert the 1st part to get those rows also, but now I get them always in result set.
In Delphi :KANAL is parameter, so it's just : instead of @

Comment: I'm gonna try your way now